# grails lesscss-resources plugin issue

Tags: grails, plugins, less

I am having trouble with the plugin. Everything seemed fine but after running the app in dev env, the page loads up but complains that it can't find the compiled css file. I am using Grails 2.0.1 and lesscss-resources 1.3.0.

Here is what I have in UiResources.groovy:

```
styling {
    defaultBundle 'styling'

    resources url: '/less/mainStyles.less', attrs:[rel: "stylesheet/less", type: 'css'], disposition: 'head', bundle: 'bundle_styling'
    resources url: '/css/other.css', disposition: 'head'
}
```

What shows up on the page is this:

```
< link href="/appName/bundle-bundle_styling_head.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" >
```

Although I can locate this file in the

```
~/.grails/2.0.1/projects/appName/tomcat/worl/Tomcat/localhost/appName/grails-resources ...
```

Grails console also complains:

```
Resources not found: /bundle-bundle_styling_head.css
```

I have been trying different things to get this to work till no avail. Did I do anything wrong here?

Comment: I had similar problem. And it was completly weird for me that other 2 definitions were working without any problem. As workaround I found that mixing less and css causes such case of problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem and found that removing the bundle option fixed the problem.  So remove ", bundle: 'bundle_styling'" making the line:

resources url: '/less/mainStyles.less', attrs:[rel: "stylesheet/less", type: 'css'], disposition: 'head'

Hope this works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware what the docs say currently in the issues section - maybe you are facing one of the bugs:

> - For the Bundle to work you must have a .css file at the end of the bundle, even if it is just a blank file.
> - Must specify the default bundle manually as this is calculated based on file extension by default.

I just had a case where I specified this in an inplace plugin (MyPluginApplicationResources.groovy)

```
resource url:'/less/eip.less', attrs:[rel: "stylesheet/less", type:'css'],defaultBundle: 'eip'
resource url: '/css/dummy.css', defaultBundle: 'eip'
```

There was no error but also no css rendered by the plugin, so I changed it to:

```
resource url:[dir: '/less', file : 'eip.less', plugin: 'my-plugin'], attrs:[rel: "stylesheet/less", type:'css'],defaultBundle: 'eip' 
resource url: '/css/dummy.css', defaultBundle: 'eip'
```

This worked for me.

dummy.css : this is an empty css file (see issues) - but I haven't tested if its really needed.